# Beginners: Dynamic filtering of foreign key field in Django CreateView form

Tags: django

Models:

```
class Instructional_Cycle(models.Model):
    date_started = models.DateField()
    date_finished = models.DateField()
    standard_tested = models.OneToOneField(Standard, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Standard(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=14, choices=subjects)
    grade_level = models.IntegerField(choices=gradeLevels)
    descriptor = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    description = models.TextField()
    essential_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

View:

```
class CycleCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Instructional_Cycle
    template_name = 'cycle_new.html'
    fields = '__all__'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('student_progress:cycles')
```

Template:

```
<!-- student_progress/cycle_new.html -->

{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Add a new instructional cycle:</h1>

    <form action="{% url 'student_progress:cycle_new' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button name="submit">add cycle</button>
    </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

The problem I'm having with this form is that the dropdown to select Instructional_Cycle.standard_tested has literally 1000 records from Standard. There's no way that the user can scroll through all of those and find the one record they want.

What I need is some way to click a link and filter the dropdown list by subject or grade_level and/or a search box, similar to what's achieved on the admin side by creating a custom admin model in admin.py like so:

```
class StandardAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('descriptor', 'description', 'essential_status')
    list_filter = ('subject', 'grade_level', 'essential_status')
    search_fields = ('descriptor',)
    inlines = [MilestoneInLine]

    def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
        queryset, use_distinct = super().get_search_results(request, queryset,         search_term)
        try:
            search_term_as_int = int(search_term)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            queryset |= self.model.objects.filter(age=search_term_as_int)
        return queryset, use_distinct
```

Please "dumb it down" for this newbie. I just finished working through Django for Beginners, and my conceptual model of how this all fits together is still full of holes. Please assume that I know hardly anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That amount of reactive work on one page will require you to be comfortable with Javascript, Ajax, etc. If that is the case, there are a number of approaches you could take that let you refresh the form with the desired options.

Alternatively, you could ask the user for the necessary data one step earlier in the process and let Django build the correct form for you in the first place by [overriding the form's default queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield).

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using something like django-ajax-select. https://github.com/crucialfelix/django-ajax-selects